# Recomile exe with debugging symbols, use for core dump generated by exe without debugging symbols

Tags: gcc, gdb

I have a core dump that lacks debugging information. The dump was caused by a not-so-reproducible bug.

Since I know exactly which version of source and the original build commands and optimization levels, is it possible to generate debugging information for this executable?

Comment: Guessing: Just build with same compiler, same switches + -g, same libraries and it might work. Then load symbols from this new binary (after executable is already loaded) with symbol-file <new_binary>.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible. Here is a rather verbose example.

Program to produce a crash (`crash.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                             
#include <string.h>

int func(char *str){
    char buff[32];
    strcpy(buff,str);
    return 0;
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    func(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile a version **without** debug symbols:

```
$ gcc crash.c -o crash
```

Compile a version **with** debug symbols:

```
$ gcc -g crash.c -o crash_debug
```

Generate a `core` file using the binary **without** debug symbols:

```
$ ./crash AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Use `gdb` and the binary **without** debug symbols to look at the core:

```
$ gdb -q ./crash  core                                                                         

warning: ~/.gdbinit.local: No such file or directory
Reading symbols from ./crash...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

warning: exec file is newer than core file.
[New LWP 7768]
Core was generated by `./crash AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040052b in func ()
```

As we can see, `gdb` could not find any debug symbols.
Now lets try to start `gdb` with the binary that was build to include debug symbols and the `core` file:

```
$ gdb -q ./crash_debug  core                                                                   

warning: ~/.gdbinit.local: No such file or directory
Reading symbols from ./crash_debug...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 7768]
Core was generated by `./crash AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040052b in func (str=0x7fff4bb66f73 'A' <repeats 52 times>) at crash.c:8
8   }
```

This works!

Another way, as @[dbrank0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395851/dbrank0) suggested, would be using the `symbol-file` command to load the symbols from a different binary:

```
$ gdb -q -c core                                                                               

warning: ~/.gdbinit.local: No such file or directory
[New LWP 7768]
Core was generated by `./crash AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040052b in ?? ()
gdb$ symbol-file crash_debug 
Reading symbols from crash_debug...done.
gdb$ bt
#0  0x000000000040052b in func (str=0x7fff4bb66f73 'A' <repeats 52 times>) at crash.c:8
#1  0x4141414141414141 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f0041414141 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000200000000 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
gdb$
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, But unfortunately it didn't work. I suspect my environment is slightly different from before. The core dump gives me a larger number of frames, with ?? instead of the symbol names.

Comment: Hey, that sucks :( Which version did you try? Did you start `gdb` with the new binary and the coder e.g. `gdb /path/to/new/bin /path/to/core` or did you run `gdb` with the core and then loaded the symbols from the new binary with `symbol-file /path/to/new/binary`? Also, did you make sure that the new binary really is build with debug infos?

Comment: I tried both, I got the `??`s when I used the recompiled binary without `symbol-file`. Sorry, but I haven't had time to look deeper into the issue.